# Programmatically authenticate with Azure AD for Application Proxy

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, azure-active-directory, owin

I have an on-premise hosted WCF service with REST endpoint which is configured for Anonymous authentication only in IIS. I installed and configured Azure App proxy connector on the server. I am able to contact the service fine with Pass-through authentication, but struggling to authenticate from a console app when Azure AD is chosen as security mechanism. I know I could have pass-through in Azure and turn on for example windows authentication in IIS, but this is unfortunately not an option in this case.

Using a browser, I am able to access the application fine, don't even need to enter credentials, our on-premise AD is connected and synchronized with Azure AD.

I followed this [walk-through](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/) despite it is not regarding application proxy, and reusing parts of code I am able to get the Access Token for my application, but when I run the http request with Authorization header I don't get the result of service operation.

Using Fiddler I can note the following:

1. I get http 302 (Found). I can see my Authorization header in request, and in response I get a cookie AzureAppProxyAnalyticCookie
2. That is followed with http 200 to login.microsoftonline.com

Example I provided link for above works fine so it is clear that I am doing something wrong. Why is Authorization header not accepted and why am I being redirected to logon page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for another service, have no idea what was wrong with the first one, but suspecting something with DNS on local server. Won't be spending more time on this, point is that I shouldn't have experienced the redirect at all, although browser handled it and managed to get me authenticated.

Comment: I have an on-prem web service that only supports windows authentication which is behind an azure app proxy. Do you have any idea how do I go about authenticating against the azure app proxy so I can access the web service behind it ?

Comment: If you configure Azure app proxy with no authentication, then you have to authenticate to you on-premise web server, usual way. If you prefer other way, than you would need to use ADAL library I think. Hope this helps.